# Change the name of local table of contents (article class, minitoc package)

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I recently manage to get a local table of contents for my `\appendix` with the package `minitoc` but I want to change the name of it to make difference between the `\parttoc` of my `\appendix` and the beginning `\parttoc`.

How can I rename `\parttoc`? Note that I added the following command in my preamble: `\usepackage[english]{babel}`

Here is my minimal working example:

```
%%%%%%%%% preamble %%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand \thepart{}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\partname}{}}
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}

%%%%%%%%% document %%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\doparttoc 
\faketableofcontents 

\section{test}
text

\appendix
\appendixpage
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Contents of Appendices}}
\part{} 
\parttoc 
\section{appendix test}
text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the name of my minitoc didn't change for the appendix and I'm quite sure that "Table of Contents" is the default name and my command `\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Table of Contents}}` didn't change a thing.

Can you help me to change this `minitoc` name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Within the body of the document, use `\renewcommand{\ptctitle}{Contents of Appendices}` (without `\addto{captionsenglish}`), or else (if you need to manage multi-lingual captions) `\renewcommand{\ptctitle}{Contents of Appendices}} \selectlanguage\english`