List of figures Appendices
I succeeded in making a separate list for the appendices for the table of contents, as follows:

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendixname}{Contents Appendices}

\newlistof{appendix}{loa}{\listappendixname}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\appendix}{
  \xpatchcmd{\ttl@addcontentsline}
    {\addcontentsline{toc}}
    {\addcontentsline{loa}}{}{}
}

\makeatother


However, I want to do the same for the figures of the appendices for the list of figures. So I want to exclude the figures of the appendices from my list of figures, and put them in a separate one. I again tried to make a list. However, this does not work. Can someone help me?
I tried:
\newcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures Appendices}
\newlistof{figure}{lof}{\listfigurename}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{}{} % Add figures to the list of figures
\makeatother



Somewhat related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688277/change-the-name-of-local-table-of-contents-article-class-minitoc-package
